# Visual Studio 2019 - TFS Queries - missing list of queries per team project / team

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

For VSTS 2019 on premise, connected via Team Explorer to a specific TeamProject / Team :

Upon click on "Work Items", a list of work items is shown, in difference from VSTS 2018, where a list of favorites and queries was shown. This list is needed also in 2019 in order to open a bulk of queries to update definitions, and in order to copy / move bulk of queries between teams and team projects.

Does anyone know where this list was moved to, or how to bypass and resolve ? Thank u

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure DevOps Work Items experience has been simplified in Visual Studio 2019.  You'll need to use the Azure DevOps web portal to manage your queries.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022, it's still possible to see the work item queries, by changing the "Work Items" experience.

From the "Tools" menu, choose "Options...". Under "Work Items"/"General", change the "Landing page" to be "Legacy experience (compatibility mode)".

Be aware: there is a note alongside saying that this will be deprecated in the next major version of Visual Studio.